# Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a subdomain in Wordpress MU and then when I go to that subdomain, I get this error:

```
Catchable fatal error: Object of class WP_Error could not be converted 
to string in /home/pahouse1/public_html/wp-content/mu-plugins/lifetime
/syncronize.php on line 450**
```

Did anyone face the same issue? What can I do about this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit more code would be nice.

Normally this means you are trying to print an object. Something like this:

```
$a = new ObjectA();
echo $a;
```

Which is not possible because, as the error says, a non-string variable (in this case a class object) couldn't be converted to a string.

You can fix this by writing a magic method `__toString()` for that class.

Full information can be found at http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#language.oop5.magic.tostring.